# How to make MediaController permanently docked

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a permanent set of media controls on the bottom of my Activity.  I've tried extending `MediaController` to do this but it overlays with the screen always, instead of having its own space.  I've also tried defining it in my layout as follows but no luck.  Any idea how I can accomplish this?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        ...
    </ScrollView>

    <.MyMediaController
        android:id="@+id/myMediaController1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the relative layout attributes?

Comment: Added relativelayout's attributes

Comment: Weird, looks fine. You can try setting different background color to each view and see the exact layout.

Comment: I've done some more testing.  If ScrollView's contents take up more than the available screen space, then whatever view I put after it (I tested with just a simple EditText for example) overlaps ScrollView while staying at the bottom of the screen.  If I use `layout_below` then it gets pushed off the screen.  Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you remove the scroll view?

Comment: The controller is at the bottom of the screen like I want.  Maybe instead of `wrap_content` for the height of the ScrollView I need to programatically set it?

Comment: The position of the media controller is not related to the scroll view since you're inside a relative layout.

Comment: As @LiorOhana says it's the RelativeLayout which is allowing the overlay effect. Change to a vertical LinearLayout and set the layout_height attributes to 0dp for both the ScrollView and MediaController and give them both layout_weight attributes to set the percentage of the screen height they occupy.

Comment: LinearLayout solved my problem.  Sorry for the delay, create an answer and I'll mark it answered.